# How do I extract text with the Xpath in Scrapy?

Tags: python-2.7, xpath, scrapy, scrapy-shell

Alright, it seems like I've tried *everything* and just can't figure out what is going on here. The direct link to the site I am trying to scrape is http://www.ammofast.com/collections/pistol/products/aguila-25-auto-acp-full-metal-jacket-50-gr-1000-round-case

And I want to extract the title and the price. My best attempts just end up returning an empty []

```
User-Ps-MacBook-Pro:ammo user$ scrapy shell "http://www.ammofast.com/collections/pistolproducts/aguila-25-auto-acp-full-metal-jacket-50-gr-1000-round-case"
...
>>> response.xpath('//div[@id="product-header-title"]/h1[@id="product-title"]/text()').extract
<bound method SelectorList.extract of []>
```

I have tried a handfull a different variations but all to no avail. I guess I don't quite fully understand the XPath structure just yet, but that's why I'm practicing :) Thanks for the help! I am on Scrapy 1.1.0 as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The price is loaded using Javascript, in the source you can see:

```
window.ShopifyAnalytics.lib.track(
          "Viewed Product",
          {"id":705964349,"name":"Aguila .25 Auto ACP Full Metal Jacket 50 Gr 1000 Round Case - 1000 \/ 50","price":"329.99","currency":"USD","sku":"","brand":"Aguila","category":".25 ACP","nonInteraction":true}
        );

            });
```

You can see if you look at the source returned that there is actually no text in `p class="price"`:

```
 <div id="purchase">
                <p class="price"></p>                                 
                <input class="btn" type="submit" name="add" id="add-to-cart" value="Add to Cart" />
              </div>

            </div><!-- /.options -->
```

What you could do is parse that function code or get the price from the option tag:

```
In [15]: response.xpath("//*[@id='product-title']/text()")
Out[15]: [<Selector xpath="//*[@id='product-title']/text()" data=u'Aguila .25 Auto ACP Full Metal Jacket 50'>]

In [16]: response.xpath("//option/text()")
Out[16]:  [<Selector xpath="//*[@id='product-select']/option/text()" data=u'1000 / 50 - $329.99'>]
```

Comment: Ok, so now I'm wondering if it's an issue with my settings or something? Cause I just copied both your inputs and all that comes back out is [ ] doesn't say anything else.

Comment: If you look at what `response.body` returns what do you see?

Comment: This is what comes back out, (https://codeshare.io/wm9vt) I tried to prettify it a little with a website and then put it on codeshare to look a tad nicer. There's quite a bit of JS in there, the only real HTML seems to be navigation bars, footer, and some of the 'template' type stuff I'd guess. If you try to just do a ctrl+F and search that for any divs or h1s it doesn't find anything, so I just the JS is what pulls that info in?

Comment: OK, what you get and what the source looks like are not the same I see `Page Not Found` in the title where if you look at the source code in the browser by right clicking and choosing view source you will see is not there. Are you sure you are using the correct url?

Comment: Right. And when I was trying to scrape the title xpath it returned the "Page Not Found". So is there a way for Scrapy to render the Javascript?

Comment: I get `response.xpath("//title").extract_first() -> u'<title>Aguila .25 Auto ACP Full Metal Jacket 50 Gr 1000 Round Case | AmmoFast.com</title>'`, yes you could use scrapy-splash https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash but you can get the data without any js loaded but there is something else happening that you need to fix. Try `scrapy shell -s USER_AGENT="Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64)" "http://www.ammofast.com/collections/pistol/products/aguila-25-auto-acp-full-metal-jacket-50-gr-1000-round-case"`

Comment: Ok, well now I feel dumb haha I thought I checked this a number of times but I guess not. When I entered the shell and pasted the URL somehow I was missing a "/" in the URL to make it "pistol/products". We good now! :)

Comment: lol, I copied the link as opposed to your code as I presumed you did the same! Anyway you would have had an issue with the price so two birds with  one stone :)